# Creating new ELF executable file

Tags: assembly, elf

Is it possible to create a new ELF executable file by using assembly? I want to make an 'empty' executable file and fill its code section after.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's an interesting article which you'll find useful: [A Whirlwind Tutorial on Creating Really Teensy ELF Executables for Linux](http://www.muppetlabs.com/~breadbox/software/tiny/teensy.html)

It starts off by analysing the size of a tiny C-based executable, and then seeks to make it small as possible by using assembler instead. He gets it from 3998 bytes down to just 45 bytes with a series of increasingly more involved analyses and tricks.

I'm sure if you read and follow along with it, you'll know more about ELF than you likely needed!

Comment: thanks for the link i will read it. I wonder in my question if i can create an ELF executable not as a independent assembly program, but if i can create one by using a function that is called from my main program. So i have an assembly program and i want to pass a string argument and create the ELF executable with that name, and after or in parallel to fill its code/data segment.